# Talend: Iterating and parsing values from array to different points tXMLMap

Tags: etl, talend

Iam working with tXMLMap and try to parse through input arrays and segregate to different output places.But Iam only getting access to first element. How can I access all data.
mysimple tXML map and flow is shown below.

[image]

The tXML map is shown below.

[image]

The post request is shown below.

[image]

Iam only getting the first object in the array as output. Second is missing. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I have ticked wrap json request in the tRESTREQUEST and in the tLogrow log is given as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><Object><date><item>item1</item><itemID>1</itemID></date><date><item>item2</item><itemID>2</itemID></date></Object></root>
```

Both objects are logged. I have also added a root document above the Object in the input of tXMLMap(row:main1) but still the output is the same, only one element is send back in response.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of tRestRequest? You are mentioning XML but you are showing JSON as well, can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Neo I have added the edits.As far as json is concerned the tRESTRequest is concerned it is configured to read input as XML or JSON.